# stale? method in rails. What does it do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/stale%3F)

The point of confusing is this for me: Why do you set etag or last_modified on the response? Isn't the client the one sending an etag and a if-modified-since header? Once the server (or proxy server) receives these client headers, isn't the server checking to see if the resource's etag and modified date match? The documentation suggest that the request is generated from scratch and not the data? Also, why are we setting the etag and last_modified on the response? Isn't it set by the client?

> stale?(options) protected Sets the etag and/or last_modified on the
>   response and checks it against the client request. If the request
>   doesn’t match the options provided, the request is considered stale
>   and should be generated from scratch. Otherwise, it’s fresh and we
>   don’t need to generate anything and a reply of "304 Not Modified" is
>   sent.
>
> Parameters:
>
> :etag :last_modified :public By default the Cache-Control header is
>   private, set this to true if you want your application to be cachable
>   by other devices (proxy caches).

What is it going? So some client request is coming in with an etag (some hash) and we check to see if that request is equal to the options in our controller that we set using stale? Here is my controller:

```
format.json_v20150501 do
          expires_in 30.minutes, public: true
          if stale?(last_modified: last_modified_for_models(recipes), etag: etag_for_models(recipes))
            render json: recipes,
              compact: true,
              serializer: PaginationSerializer,
              each_serializer: Api::V20150315::RecipeSerializer
          end
        end
```

I don't get what is happening...

Comment: I answered this one on another question you posted. Just like it says, stale? checks the options provided (those args) to determine whether the object has been modified and therefore needs to be regenerated.

Comment: this might be helpful re: etags. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/08/rails-5-switches-from-strong-etags-to-weak-tags.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Edited my question. You guys can write an answer and I'll totally accept it!

Answer (score 6):

stale? checks the options provided (those args) to determine whether the object has been modified and therefore needs to be regenerated (in case of cacheing).

regarding the etags, reading this might be helpful: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/08/rails-5-switches-from-strong-etags-to-weak-tags.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: What does it check the options with?

Comment: against the cached data. that's why it's checking when it was last modified.

Comment: Huh? Meaning the rails endpoint here checks the options (the args) it generates with the cached data? Doesn't Rails check the options it generates with the request?

Comment: Also if it's not stale, does the client get cached data from the browser or some proxy server's cache (memcached or something?)